# Google Cloud Vision API request from React webcam error: "No image present"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to make a Google Cloud Vision API request from a React camera component, with my image being sent directly to the API as a base64 encoded string. Specifically, I'm using the react-camera npm to get a user's photo through their webcam or front-facing (selfie) mobile camera.

The error I keep getting is "Error: No image present." After several hours trying various ways to encode, decode, stringify, and otherwise massage the blob data, I haven't been able to get the image into a format that works. Here are the relevant sections of my camera.js component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Camera from 'react-camera';
import 'react-html5-camera-photo/build/css/index.css'
...

export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.takePicture = this.takePicture.bind(this);
    this.state = {blob:''};
    this.confirmphoto.bind(this)
  }

  takePicture() {
     this.camera.capture()
     .then(blob => {
        this.img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
        this.img.onload = () => {
           URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src)
        }
        this.setState({
           blob:blob
        })
     })
  }

  confirmphoto() {
     console.log("blob contents:", this.state.blob);
     axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_BACK_END_SERVER + 'submitChallenge', this.state.blob)
     .then((res)=>{
        console.log(res);
     })
     .catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
     });//end axios call
  }
```

And here are the relevant parts of my API request route:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
...
const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');
const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

function pictureIsValid(pictureFile) {

   // Stringify raw blob data
   var newObj = JSON.stringify(pictureFile);
   console.log(newObj);

   // Convert blob to base64
   var newObj = Buffer.from(newObj).toString('base64');
   console.log(newObj);

   // JSON request for Google Cloud Vision API

   const request = {
      "requests":[
          {
            "image":{
               "content": newObj
            },
            "features":[
               {
                  "type":"LABEL_DETECTION",
                  "maxResults":1
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   };

   // Making the request
   client.annotateImage(request)
   .then(function(res){
      console.log("result: ", res);
   })
   .catch(function(err){
      console.log(err);
   });
};

router.post('/', function (req, res) {
   var data = req.body;
   console.log("data passed type:", typeof data);
   var test = pictureIsValid(data);
   res.sendStatus(200).send();
});
```

Using strategically placed console logs, the data does appear to be passed but as an object, and it is several lines of encrypted data that looks like this:

```
{ ' ����\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0000H\
u0006\b\u0007\u0007\b\n\u0011\u000b\n\t\t\n\u0014\u000f\
u0017\u001a\u001d% \u001a\u001c#\u001c\u0017\u0017!,!#\'
(***\u0019\u001f.1-)1%)*(\u0001\u0007\b\b\n\t\n\u0013\u0
00b\u000b\u0013(\u001b\u0017\u001b(((((((( ...u000f\u000
7���j���_\'i�F;��`�Ҿ���\u0017R�l�פ�)�q�y��f��\r��i�S�S\\
�4\u0010\nv)qJ)�W\u0013\u0014���.*�q���8�LRaq���8�*����':
'' }
```

This is what is showing in the terminal after the base64 conversion of the foregoing:

```
eyLvv73vv73vv73vv71cdTAwMDBcdTAwMTBKRklGXHUwMDAwXHUwMDAx
XHUwMDAxXHUwMDAxXHUwMDAwSFx1MDAwMEhcdTAwMDBcdTAwMDDvv73v
v71cdTAwMDBcZkFwcGxlTWFya1xu77+977+9XHUwMDAw77+9XHUwMDAw
XHUwMDA3XHUwMDA1XHUwMDA1XHUwMDA2XHUwMDA1XHUwMDA1XHUwMDA3
XHUwMDA2XHUwMDA2XHUwMDA2XGJcdTAwMDdcdTAwMDdcYlxuXHUwMDEx
XHUwMDBiXG5cdFx0XG5cdTAwMTRcdTAwMGZcdTAwMGZcZlx1MDAxMVx1
MDAxOFx1MDAxNVx1MDAxOVx1MDAxOVx1MDAxN1x1MDAxNVx1MDAx ...
```

It looks like base64, which is what the Google Cloud Vision API is supposed to accept, but I keep getting back the error that there is "no image present." I've also tried submitting the blob itself, stringified and non-stringified versions of the blob and the base64 looking data.

I have a sneaking suspicion that the blob data is not even image data to begin with. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong? Do I need to switch in a different camera/webcam node package?

Comment: The `request` object looks weird. Are you sure you are following the right pattern?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings I thought it looked weird too, but it's practically copied/pasted from the documentation at https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/request.